# Avoid "Save as" dialog while converting Excel to XML using VBA script

Tags: vba, excel, filepath

I am trying to write a VBA Script which converts the excel file to XML. I am fetching the file name using `Application.GetSaveAsFilename()` function. But this function opens up the "Save As" dialog box. I want to suppress the dialog such that the user is not prompted to manually click save each time the code is run. Instead, the XML should be silently generated at the location hard-coded.

Code:

```vba
Sub BasicRTE()
    Dim FileName As Variant
    Dim Sep As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim autoSetFileName As String
    Dim folderName As String
    Dim location As Integer

    ChDrive (Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, 1))
    ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
    ChDir ".."
    ChDir "InputFiles"
    Application.SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
    FileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
      InitialFileName:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name, _
      FileFilter:="Xml Files (*.xml),*.xml")
    location = InStrRev(FileName, "\", , vbTextCompare)
    folderName = Mid(FileName, 1, location - 1)        
    For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, Ws.Name, "#", vbTextCompare) <> 1 Then
            ExportToMyXMLFile FName:=CStr(folderName & "\" & Ws.Name & ".xml"), Sep:=CStr(Sep), _
            AppendData:=False, Ws:=Ws
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the code for ExportToMyXMLFile?

Comment: @Mark Sorry didn't include the code for ExportToMyXml as that part of code was running perfectly without any issue so thought it would be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the only thing you are using `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` for is to get the path to the `InputFiles` path with respect to the location of `ThisWorkbook` into `folderName`.  The operating system already provides that!  The following changes should work (but I have not tested them myself):

```
' fileName = ...                 ' don't need this
' location = ...                 ' or this
folderName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\..\InputFiles"   ' e.g., C:\Users\Foo\Documents\..\InputFiles
```

Alternatively, if you want a cleaner string,

```
Dim location as Long     ' Never use Integer unless you are calling Win32 or something else esoteric

' Don't need any of this unless later code relies on the current directory
' (which it shouldn't, for robustness).
'ChDrive (Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, 1))
'ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
'ChDir ".."
'ChDir "InputFiles"
'Application.SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
'FileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
'  InitialFileName:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name, _
'  FileFilter:="Xml Files (*.xml),*.xml")
folderName = ThisWorkbook.Path
location = InStrRev(folderName, "\", , vbTextCompare)
folderName = Mid(folderName, 1, location) & "InputFiles"
For Each ws ...
```

The `InStrRev`+`Mid` drops the last path component, just like `..`, and then the `& "InputFiles"` puts `InputFiles` on the end.

One caution: `ThisWorkbook.Path` is an empty string for a new, unsaved workbook.  Make sure your workbook is saved to disk before using the above.

**Edit** another caution: you are using `ws.Name` directly in making filenames.  However, sheet names can include text that filenames cannot.  I can name a sheet `CON` or `<foo>`, but neither of those is valid in a filename.  [Here's](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28025657/Vba-Code-Eliminate-Illegal-Characters-from-a-filename.html#a38870261) one example of sanitizing filenames (a quick Google result — not tested).  However, even that example does not appear to check for [reserved names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx).

<sub>Reserved names: CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9 per [MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)).</sub>

Comment: The workbook will be presaved as this will be used in my automation framework so using ThisWorkbook.path is not an issue. Also the sheet names are predefined so less chance it will be a reserved name.
The code worked like a charm. 
Thanks !!